# Understanding notation in Bias-Variance decomposition in Elements of Statistical Learning

Tags: machine-learning, probability, mathematical-statistics, prediction, expected-value

I'm going through Elements of Statistical Learning and I'm having a bit of trouble understanding this bit of notation from Chapter 2 (this example is (2.27))

$$EPE(x_0) = E_{y_o|x_o}E_T(y_0 - \hat{y}_0)^2$$

Here, $T$ is the set of N=1000 training samples drawn from a uniform distribution, and $Y = X^T\beta + \epsilon$  and $\epsilon \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$.

My question is about what $E_T$ means in the $EPE$ equation. I get that $T$ is a random variable, representing the possible draws of N training samples from the uniform distribution, and that $E_T$ is the expectation with respect to $T$, however I'm not sure how exactly to properly understand how $T$ interacts with $(y_0 - \hat{y}_0)^2$. I know it must, since y is a function of $x \sim T$ with some noise, but I'm having a hard time making that concrete.

If I were to write this out as an integral, how would I get $T$ to show up in the inner integral?

I think the integral would look something like this

$$\int_{y_0\sim P(y_0|x_0)} \left(\int_{t\in T} (y_0 - \hat{y}_0)^2 P(T=t) d\mu(t)   \right) dy_0$$

I'm trying to figure out how to make $(y_0 - \hat{y}_0)^2$ have a $t$ term so that the integral makes sense.

Comment: I believe I figured it out: E_T is the expectation of the training set, so E_T is really the joint expectation of the X and Y that make up $\beta$ in the least-squares fit. So $(y_0 - \hat{y}_0)^2$ under the expectation w.r.t. X and Y is $(y_0 - (X^T X)^{-1} X^T Y * x_0)^2$